# Masstransit in docker using Request/Response model, Request Consumer exception, host not found while responding

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I'm quite new to Masstransit/RabbitMq and I encountered a problem cannot deal with.
I have a Rabbitmq server running in docker, also a small microservice in docker container which consumes an event. Beside this I run a windows service on the host machine, which has the task to send the event via the masstransit Request/Response model to the microservice. The interesting thing is that the event arrives to the consumer as supposed but when I try to response the context.RespondAsync from the consume method I get an exception

```
R-FAULT rabbitmq://autbus/exi_bus 80c60000-eca5-3065-0093-08d62a09d168 HwExi.Extensions.Events.ReservationCreateOrUpdateEvent HwExi.Api.Consumers.ReservationCrateOrUpdateConsumer(00:00:07.8902444) The host was not found for the specified address: rabbitmq://127.0.0.1/bus-SI-GEPE-HwService.Api-oddyyy8cwwagkoscbdmnwncfrg?durable=false&autodelete=true, MassTransit.EndpointNotFoundException: The host was not found for the specified address: rabbitmq://127.0.0.1/bus-SI-GEPE-HwService.Api-oddyyy8cwwagkoscbdmnwncfrg?durable=false&autodelete=true
```

I'm using this model to messaging between microservices without any problem and its working properly in another queue.

Here is the yaml of microservice / Bus

```
exiapi:
image: exiapi
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Service/HwExi.Api/Dockerfile
ports:
  - "54542:80"
environment:
  "BUS_USERNAME": "guest"
  "BUS_PASSWORD": "guest"
  "BUS_HOST": "rabbitmq://autbus"
  "BUS_URL": "exi_bus"
autbus:
image: rabbitmq:3-management
hostname: autbus
ports:
  - "15672:15672"
  - "5672:5672"
  - "5671:5671"
volumes:
  - ~/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
```

the config of the windows service:

```
"Bus": {
"Username": "guest",
"Password": "guest",
"Host": "rabbitmq://127.0.0.1",
"Url": "exi_bus"
```

},

The windows service connects like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rmq =>
            {
                var host = rmq.Host(new Uri(options.Value.Bus.Host), "/", h =>
                {
                    h.Username(options.Value.Bus.Username);
                    h.Password(options.Value.Bus.Password);
                });
                rmq.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Fanout;
            });
        }).As<IBusControl>().As<IBus>().As<IPublishEndpoint>().SingleInstance();
```

The microservice inside container connects like this

```
 public static class BusExtension
{
    public static void InitializeBus(this ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly assembly)
    {
        builder.Register(context =>
        {
            return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rmq =>
            {
                var host = rmq.Host(new Uri(Constants.Bus.Host), "/", h =>
                {
                    h.Username(Constants.Bus.UserName);
                    h.Password(Constants.Bus.Password);
                });
                rmq.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Fanout;
                rmq.ReceiveEndpoint(host, Constants.Bus.Url, configurator =>
                {
                    configurator.LoadFrom(context);
                });
            });
        }).As<IBusControl>().As<IBus>().As<IPublishEndpoint>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterConsumers(assembly);
    }

    public static void StartBus(this IContainer container, IApplicationLifetime lifeTime)
    {
        var bus = container.Resolve<IBusControl>();
        var busHandler = TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.StartAsync());
        lifeTime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => busHandler.Stop());
    }
}
```

than windows service fires the event like this:

```
var reservation = ReservationRepository.Get(message.KeyId, message.KeySource);
        var operation = await ReservationCreateOrUpdateClient.Request(new ReservationCreateOrUpdateEvent { Reservation = reservation });
        if (!operation.Success)
        {
            Logger.LogError("Fatal error while sending reservation create or update message to exi web service");
            return;
        }
```

Finally the microservice catches the event like this.

```
public class ReservationCrateOrUpdateConsumer : IConsumer<ReservationCreateOrUpdateEvent>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ReservationCreateOrUpdateEvent> context)
    {
        await context.RespondAsync(new MessageOperationResult<bool>
        {
            Result = true,
            Success = true
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using autofac to register the requestclient in windows service:

```
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        ServiceAddress = new Uri($"{Configurarion.Bus.Host}/{Configurarion.Bus.Url}");

            builder.Register(c => new MessageRequestClient<ReservationCreateOrUpdateEvent, MessageOperationResult<bool>>(c.Resolve<IBus>(), ServiceAddress, Timeout))
            .As<IRequestClient<ReservationCreateOrUpdateEvent, MessageOperationResult<bool>>>().SingleInstance();
```

Can anybody help debug this out? Also share opinion if this structure is a proper one, maybe I should  use https for sending message from the client machine to my microservice environment, and convert it to the bus via a gateway or similar approach more suitable? Thanks

Comment: To communicate using aliases, they need to run in one container. You can also use docker-compose. Otherwise, you need to reach out to the host machine to the port you have mapped. When I use RMQ container locally, I reach it with rabbitmq://localhost.

Comment: Thanks Alexey for tips, a bit difficult to follow your thoughts however, what aliases do you mention? also I'm using docker-compose, and I try to reach the host machine with rabbitmq://127.0.0.1 I also tried localhost with the same result. My plan is that there will be more client machines with pure windows install, no docker, and they sending messages to a server machine which runs RabbitMq server, microservices and so on in docker, this is the reason I dont use containerized service instead of Windows service

Comment: Maybe the route cause is, that Masstransit tries to respond on 127.0.0.1 but inside container this ip is not available for the host machine, host machine ip inside container should be resolved somehow

Comment: Have you tried to ping the RMQ hostname that you are trying to reach from MassTransit, from a terminal on your machine?

Comment: yes, it turns out this is a pure docker problem, if I don't set network mode in compose file, it will start containers in bridge mode, you can achive ports from host to container but not opposite, I found one solution, if i start my microservice with network_mode: "host", then host as 127.0.0.1 available in the container, and Masstransite able to send response. I'm not sure this is the best solution, and what will happen if I deploy to linux and try to send messages from client machines, but currently it's ok, thanks again for tips

Comment: It's actually not a good idea to run infrastructure in containers. So, consider deploying RMQ as a service on the host machine. Services are fine when running in containers.

Comment: I see, thanks for advice, I consider this solution!